# How to run a HTML project with PHP files using Tomcat 7 under Eclipse IDE?

Tags: php, eclipse, tomcat7, phpeclipse

I have searched every where but I can't find an answer to my question.

I have Eclipse Juno installed on arch Linux, I have installed Apache Tomcat 7 as a server and PHPEclipse for writing PHP scripts.

I have created a project with various HTML pages, but I need some PHP scripts to be run inside this project. I have installed PHPEclipse for this reason, in *run configurations* I have set the PHP executable directory, but if I use the internal Eclipse browser the PHP doesn't get parsed at all, it appear's to me as regular text. If I run access the page in an external web browser (Firefox) I get a white screen.

I am going really mad on this problem, can somebody give me some help?